# Should I make one GridBagConstraint object for each component

Tags: java

As the title says, should I make one GridBagConstraint object for each component? In

> java how to program 8th edition

they make a method named addComponent, however when I read about GridBagLayout I always end up reading that I should not use the same constraint-object. What should I follow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly safe to reuse the same `GridBagConstraint` instance for each component added with `add`. The [Sun GridBagLayout example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html#gridbagExample) reuses the same `GridBagConstraint` instance. Just be aware all `GridBagConstraint` fields will be used, thus you may need to reset some of them.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at GridBagLayout's method calls that are called while adding any given component, the final call goes to:

```
public void setConstraints(Component comp, GridBagConstraints constraints) {
    comptable.put(comp, (GridBagConstraints)constraints.clone());
}
```

Here, the GridBagLayout is creating a clone of the constraints object passed in which means that each component being added has a fresh copy of the GridBagConstraints. So, it should be perfectly fine to reuse the GridBagConstraints object and making changes to it as necessary.

Regards